# R Shiny: how to make input value conditionally reactive (on another input)?

Tags: r, reactive-programming, shiny

I want the app to load a single time with default values, but become reactive only when the user types the correct password. To keep things simple let's work from the Rstudio template (minutely edited):

**ui.R**:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(  
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(              
          passwordInput("pw", "Password:"),

          sliderInput("nbins",
                      "Number of bins:",
                      min = 1,
                      max = 50,
                      value = 30)
      ),    
    mainPanel(
    plotOutput("histo")
    )
)))
```

**server.R**:

```
PASSWORD <- "test"

library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$histo <- renderPlot({
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$nbins + 1)
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
})
```

There are two reactive inputs `pw` and `nbins`. My question is: How could the code be extended to make `nbins` (behavior) switch between *reactive* and *non-reactive* depending on the input `pw` being equal to `PASSWORD`?

Comment: Is `conditionalPanel()` what you're looking for?

Comment: @VanceLopez Thanks, but no, I'm looking how to do this on the server side. If that is possible at all. How would you fix this with `conditionalPanel()`?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you mean by "switch between reactive and non-reactive". Are you wanting to prevent a user from interacting with `nbins` unless they have the correct password, but still want to display `output$histo` based on the original values of the input?

Comment: @VanceLopez exactly!

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution:

```
PASSWORD <- "test"

    library(shiny)

    shinyServer(function(input, output) {
            bins <- eventReactive(input$nbins, {
                    if (input$pw == PASSWORD) {
                    bins <- seq(min(faithful[, 2]), max(faithful[, 2]), length.out = input$nbins + 1) 
                    } else {
                    bins <- seq(min(faithful[, 2]), max(faithful[, 2]), length.out = 30 + 1)      
                    }
            })

            output$histo <- renderPlot({
                    x <- faithful[, 2]                       
                    hist(x, breaks = bins(), col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
            })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Valter's answer, you can use `shinyjs` to enable/disable interactivity with the input widget.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs) # install shinyjs

shinyUI(fluidPage(  
  useShinyjs(), # activate
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(              
      passwordInput("pw", "Password:"),

      sliderInput("nbins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("histo")
    )
  )))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observe({
    if(input$pw != "PASSWORD") shinyjs::hide("nbins") else shinyjs::show("nbins")
  })

  output$histo <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, 2]

    # will 'reset' bins to original value if incorrect pw
    if(input$pw != "PASSWORD") {
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = 30 + 1)
    } else {
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$nbins + 1)
    }

    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
})
```